# Laravel 9 "The password field is required." Error When Resetting Password

Tags: php, laravel

I am using the built-in authentication screens with my Laravel 9 app.  The `forgot-password.blade.php` has a single field for `email`.  Why do I get the `The password field is required.` error when I presumable don't remember my password?

**forgot-password.blade.php**

```
<div class="w-lg-500px bg-body rounded shadow-sm p-10 p-lg-15 mx-auto">
        <form class="form w-100" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="text-center mb-10">
                <h1 class="text-dark mb-3">Forgot Password ?</h1>
                <div class="text-gray-400 fw-bold fs-4">Enter your email to reset your password.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="fv-row mb-10">
                <x-label for="email" :value="__('Email')" class="form-label fw-bolder text-gray-900 fs-6"/>

                <x-input id="email" class="form-control form-control-solid" type="email" name="email"
                         :value="old('email')" required autofocus/>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center pb-lg-0">
                <button type="submit" id="kt_password_reset_submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary fw-bolder me-4">
                    <span class="indicator-label">Submit</span>
                    <span class="indicator-progress">Please wait...
                                    <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/" class="btn btn-lg btn-light-primary fw-bolder">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**PasswordResetLinkController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class PasswordResetLinkController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display the password reset link request view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.forgot-password');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming password reset link request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        ]);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $status == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? back()->with('status', __($status))
                    : back()->withInput($request->only('email'))
                            ->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
}
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('login');

    Route::post('login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store']);

    Route::get('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.request');

    Route::post('forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.email');

    Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('password.reset');

    Route::post('reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->name('password.update');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('verify-email', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->name('verification.notice');

    Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');

    Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('throttle:6,1')
                ->name('verification.send');

    Route::get('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
                ->name('password.confirm');

    Route::post('confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store']);

    Route::post('logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->name('logout');
});
```

Comment: what about your routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the route action of your form, you are sending the request to the route named `password.update`, but the good route is `password.request`, just change in the view

```html
...
   <form class="form w-100" method="POST" action="{{ route('password.request') }}">
...
```